# Prove that if $B-A = C-A$ then $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

What I have is this:

if $x∈B\backslash A$

then by the equality to $C\backslash A$,

$x∈C\backslash A$

so $x∈C, x∈B, x\notin A, x∈B\cap C$

this shows that:

$B\subseteq C$.

if $x∈C\backslash A$

{repeat of what was shown earlier}

$C\subseteq B$.

thus if, $B\backslash A=C\backslash A$, then $B=C$.

I'm not sure if it's correct though, I feel pretty insecure about it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note: "prove" does not equal "proof".

Comment: What does $B-A$ mean here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct lol.

Comment: B-A means elements in set B but not that which also belongs to A

Comment: But then what you're trying to prove is not generally true. For example take two different sets $B\ne C$ and let $A=B\cup C$ then we have $B-A=\emptyset=C-A$.

Comment: sorry i meant to say what I'm proving is that for B-A=C-A to be true, B=C

Comment: $B\smallsetminus A= C\smallsetminus A$ does not infer $B=C$. Witness when we let $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,3\}, C=\{2,3\}$. Then we have a case where $B\smallsetminus A= C\smallsetminus A$ is true, but not $B=C$.  @GiancarloGatti

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to prove is false. For example let $B\ne C$ and $A=B\cup C$ then we have $B\setminus A = \emptyset = C\setminus A$.

The error is that you from $x\in B\setminus A$ conclude correctly that $x\in C$, but that only prooves that $(B\setminus A)\subseteq C$. We can have $x\in B\cap A$ which is in $B$, but not in $B\setminus A$ - those elements does not then require to be in $C$.

---

On the other hand if it were the symmetric difference (the set of elements that's in precisely one of the sets): $B\triangle A=C\triangle A$ it would imply that $B=C$. You can prove this by switching on the cases $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$ respectively.

Comment: I know it is generally wrong, but the question is that assume B-A = C-A, why is that B has to equal C for the assumption to be correct

Comment: @Giancarlo: $B$ *doesn't* have to equal $C$ for the stated assumption to be correct, as skyking proved. Now, it is possible that you have mis-stated the problem, as Andres points out. Perhaps some condition has been given about $A$ that you omitted. Perhaps the assumption is that $B\setminus A=C\setminus A$ *for all sets* $A.$

Answer (score 1):

You need some further hypothesis, such as $A \subset C,B$. In this case, let $x \in C$.

**hint:** there are two cases.

Case 1: $x \in A$

Case 2:  $x \in C-A$.

Both follow immediately.